# How to change arguments on detach/attach in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, arguments

I have a fragment which is called from an activity, when this fragment is loaded it generate some charts. Now, I have to update those charts, but the data used to update those charts comes from the argument of the fragment.

```
public static BaseFragment newInstance(WholeReportsData wholeReportsDataFB, WholeReportsData wholeReportsDataTeam) {
    MainReportFragment fragment = new MainReportFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(ARG_WHOLEREPORTSINFO_FB, wholeReportsDataFB);
    args.putParcelable(ARG_WHOLEREPORTSINFO_TEAM, wholeReportsDataTeam);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@android.support.annotation.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mWholeReportsDataFB = getArguments().getParcelable(ARG_WHOLEREPORTSINFO_FB);
        mWholeReportsDataTeam = getArguments().getParcelable(ARG_WHOLEREPORTSINFO_TEAM);
    } else {
        mWholeReportsDataFB = new WholeReportsData();
        mWholeReportsDataTeam = new WholeReportsData();
    }
}
```

I'm updating the fragment, like the next code, but I don't know how to update the arguments.

```
private void reloadFragment(){

        mReportsPresenter = ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getReportPresenter();

        mWholeReportsDataFB = new WholeReportsData(null, "", true);
        mWholeReportsDataTeam = new WholeReportsData();
        mReportsPresenter.requestReportsInfo(new ReportsRequestParams(getActivity(), ReportsRequestParams.TYPE_FAMILYBANKER));
        if (SessionUserResult.getInstance().getFamilyBanker().isEsSupervisor()) {
            mReportsPresenter.requestReportsInfo(new ReportsRequestParams(getActivity(), ReportsRequestParams.TYPE_TEAM));
            mWholeReportsDataTeam.setLoadingService(true);
        }



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).commitNow();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(this).commitNow();
        } else {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
        }

    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared view model between activity and fragments and update charts, 
check this [How to communicate between fragments and activity using ViewModel](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-viewmodel-ca733233a51c)

or you can check if the arguments not null, then update them else set new arguments,

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putLong(Constants.EXTRA_DO_ID, doId);
    bundle.putInt(Constants.EXTRA_DO_OPTIONS_DIALOG_MODE, MODE_GET_INSPIRE_BY_DO);
    if (fragment.getArguments() != null) {
        fragment.getArguments().putAll(bundle);
    } else
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: SharedViewModel will handle this, check the article